# error TS2307: after gulp build error cannot find module in angular/core

Tags: angularjs, angular, typescript, gulp

I'm upgrading a angular 1 app to angular 4, I have installed all required node modules.
In VS code I'm not getting any compiler error but when running gulp build getting  error

> error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core.
>   My app.module.ts :

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { UpgradeModule } from '@angular/upgrade/static';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    UpgradeModule
  ]
})
export class AppModule {
  constructor(private upgrade: UpgradeModule) { }
  ngDoBootstrap() {
    this.upgrade.bootstrap(document.body, ['heroApp'], { strictDi: true });
  }
}
```

tsconfig.json :

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": [ "es2015", "dom" ],
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true
  }
}
```

Error :

```
error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core'.
```

Thanks and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: how did u made ur basic application of nagular4? did u use angular cli?

Comment: I'm upgrading angular to 4 by installing angular package through npm